# Java in IntelliJ IDEA: How to view the variable value when debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

In the past, I can view the variable value in Variables and the tail of one line code.Maybe some setting were changed, so that I only view the variable value in Variables now. [Red arrow in the upper right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgEpD.png) Please teach me how to restore! Thanks!

Comment: build in debug mode and add debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the IntelliJ Documentation....it suggests**

Go to the "Debug Tool Window", click "Settings", check "Show Values Inline"

[IntelliJ Docs - Inline Values View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inline-debugging.html)